# Merge and replace pandas dataframe rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table in dataframe that where I would like to merge and replace the similar rows based on same date and lap number. But the condition is: the Start Date and Start time will be taken from the first incident of each Lap number and End Date and Time will be taken from the last row of the lap.

[image]

That means the final table should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
df=df.groupby('Lap Number').first().reset_index()
df['End Date']=df.groupby('Lap Number').last().reset_index()['End Date']
```

`groupby`+`first`+`reset_index` is the solution.

You'll get the desired output from this.

Comment: I tried this. But I am getting only the first occurrence of each lap. The Start Date and Start time need to be taken from the first incident of each Lap and End Date and Time will be taken from the latest End date and time for the same lap.